# Count down issue in Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, android-toast

I created a `CountDownTimer` before starting a recording. The part of code:

```
if(bitRateBoolean && timeBoolean && name) {
             toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registration will start in 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                         toast.show();

             new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }

                  public void onFinish() {
                          toast.cancel();
                      rec();
                  }
               }.start();             

     }
```

I want that `rec()` starts after 5 seconds and the toast displays the countdown. But this doesn't work. It displays the countdown but seems that it count down every two seconds instead one. i have to wait the double time before the toast disappears. Something's wrong in the code?

Comment: i dont think something is wrong, toast probably takes 2 seconds to disappear. use a textview to display the current time left and check again.

Comment: IIRC LENGTH_LONG is 5 or 7 seconds

Comment: LENGTH_LONG toasts take 3.5 seconds to disappear and they are drawn on top of another. Is this your problem?

Comment: not exactly.. when it displays "remains 2 seconds" before the rec, the rec starts. It's not..sync.. I don't know exactly how explain :(

Answer (score 1):

[Countdown Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)  from what I read here the problem is the toast time, since it takes more than two secs. The next onClick is called only after the first one is finished. If your toast takes longer than 1 sec( 'Toast.LENGTH_LONG' which it definitely does) then the next call to onTick will not be after 1 second.

> private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
>   private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds

those are the Toast default values for LENGTH_LONG and LENGTH_SHORT. 

 my advice is  to use [Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) instead of Toast

Comment: mmh, yes i think this is the problem.. I tryied using a textview and it works.. The problem now is that the textview doesn't disappears and remains : ` "seconds remaining 1"` . I need "reset" the textview onFinish()

Comment: in that case you could try something like textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)